# NAMESPACE dependencies: rlang, dplyr or anything else

Tags: r, dplyr, devtools, rlang

I program with pipes in my package, also using `:=` function (or operator?). It seems to originate from `rlang`, and doesn't seem to be exported from `dplyr`. Is it valid to use `importFrom(rlang,":=")` in the `NAMESPACE` of my package?

Comment: Do you get an error or warning or anything? Is there a reason you think it might be invalid? Also for setting things like that up you might want to check out the `usethis` package, specifically `usethis::use_tidy_eval()`

Comment: Since I'm new to package development and fairly new to `tidyverse`, that's exactly the question: where the invalid code starts and a better style begins. Good advice to check the warnings.